# How to add mutiple actions (programs) in created task via command line?

Tags: windows, command, task, line, scheduler

I'm trying to add multiple actions to created task via command line. It works fine with one program but I can't figure out how to add more than just single action.

This works fine with single program:

```
schtasks.exe /create /TN TEST /SC ONSTART /TR "'C:\Some Path\Some Program.exe' -SomeSwitch"
```

In order to add mutiple programs I've tried these commands

```
schtasks.exe /create /TN TEST /SC ONSTART /TR "'C:\Some Path\Some Program1.exe' -SomeSwitch" /TR "'C:\Some Path\Some Program2.exe' -SomeSwitch"
```

I got error saying that `/TR` switch can't be used more than once 
so I've also tried without extra `/TR` switch and nothing.

```
schtasks.exe /create /TN TEST /SC ONSTART /TR "'C:\Some Path\Some Program1.exe' -SomeSwitch"  "'C:\Some Path\Some Program2.exe' -SomeSwitch"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure how it works now, but in XP you could schedule only one program per task. But if nothing else works, you can still make a simple batch which will launch each of your .exes and schedule that.

You can use either `start` or `call` depending on if you want to catch errors or something.

Comment: In GUI (Task Scheduler) you can add multiple actions so I assumed that this could be also possible via command line.